# Angular2 and AdminLTE control-sidebar dont show when page is open by routerLink

Tags: angular

i have Angular2 application and I use AdminLTE. I have problem with show control-sidebar. 
Control sidebar opens when page is redirect or open with `<a href="page/something">Link in menu</a>`  but when i open page using `<a routerLink="page/something">Link in menu</a>` (dont refresh) control-sidebar dont open and link redirect to `localhost:4200/#`

My code is:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar">Open sidebar</a>
<aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark"></aside>
```

I would like to open pages using routerLink and i would like to open control-sidebar.
Has anyone solved a similar problem? Where could be a mistake?
thanks

Comment: You should not use `<a href="#"` as if force page location change and navigation to new location. Use `(click)` handlers or child `route-outlet`'s to control sidebar state

Comment: Thanks, but how i show control-sidebar manually when call click event method? how to use `route-outlet`? Its same as `router-outlet`? I know only `router-outlet` and i use this for loading component after click on link with routerLink. Could you please describe the solution?

Comment: Actually you can attach click handler to your sidebar control and react to it just with changing visibility state (show-hide by clicking on it). Or you can have route-outlets tree structure, where master page define sidebar + container and container has it's own route outlet to load your component (but this solution is more complicated, so try to reuse first approach)

Answer (score 2):

I have also used the same theme and faced same problem.
My problem was after login; my admin portal gets loaded with sidebar menu.
and when i clicked on any menu it redirected to "localhost:4200/#".

So in login component after successful login instead of navigating using router, I have navigated to admin panel using below code :

*`window.location.assign('/instances/active');`*

Below code I have commented

```
//this.router.navigate(['/instances/active']);
```

and menu worked as expected there after in admin portal.

Hope this might help you.
You may use $windows service as well for this.

Comment: But when I am using the window.location.assign and running war on we server, It's not coming with "Context path" while this.router.navigate is putting URL with context path. Did you find any solution for it ???

Comment: @GauravTyagi - I have not faced any issue after this fix.